C# I want to display the received data using a scottplot5.0 graph and display real time on the X-axis
ScottPlot5.0
//[Graph Init Code]
            formsPlot1.Plot.Axes.SetLimitsY(-5, 15); // y limit -5,15
            formsPlot1.Plot.Axes.DateTimeTicksBottom();
            
            formsPlot2.Plot.Axes.SetLimitsY(-5, 15); // y limit -5,15
            formsPlot2.Plot.Axes.DateTimeTicksBottom();

            formsPlot1.Plot.YLabel("Voltage", 18);
            formsPlot2.Plot.YLabel("Voltage", 18);

            formsPlot1.Refresh();
            formsPlot2.Refresh();

//[Timer Code]
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

            double DateTime_Now = DateTime.Now.ToOADate();

            double x2 = m_i * 13;
            double y2 = Math.Sin(x2);

            logger[0].Add(DateTime_Now, y2); 
            m_i++;  // m_i -> start for 0

As a result of running the current code, time is displayed on the x-axis in real time, but the x-axis time interval and scale cannot be set due to auto scale. What is the method of fixing the specified time interval and scale?
For example, the total length of the x-axis is 1 hour, expressed in 10-minute increments. After one hour, the data is pushed back one space.

I think you can just do this:
var now = DateTime.Now;
var anHourAgo = now - TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
formsPlot1.Plot.Axes.SetLimitsX(anHourAgo.ToOADate(), now.ToOADate());

You'll probably want to read this, which covers converting DateTimes to something you can pass to ScottPlot. ScottPlot uses OLE automation dates, which is stored as the number of (fractional) days since the midnight of 30 December 1899. It's a little weird, but it's common in the Microsoft world. https://scottplot.net/cookbook/5.0/DateTimeAxes/DateTimeAxisMixed/
You'll probably also want to see this, as I'm not sure if ScottPlot will give you 10 minute intervals, it'll probably try to give you something smaller so long as it has the space for all of the ticks. This example covers how to pass in your own tick generation function.   https://scottplot.net/cookbook/5.0/DateTimeAxes/DateTimeAxisFixedIntervalTicks/
The TLDR for that article is that you can do
xAxis.TickGenerator = new DateTimeFixedInterval(
    new Minute(), 10, // 10 minutes between major ticks (which are labelled and larger)
    new Minute(), 2, // 2 minutes between minor ticks
    dt => startTime); // Specify the time at which the ticks start
                      // this lets you ensure they are (for example) an 
                      // hour apart AND on the hour (rather than being 
                      // 10:19, 11:19, 12:19, etc)

The xAxis is returned by formsPlot1.Plot.Axes.DateTimeTicksBottom() which you already call. You can also get it from the formsPlot1.Plot.Axes.Bottom property.
The rest of the DateTime axis articles are available here, if they're helpful for you: https://scottplot.net/cookbook/5.0/DateTimeAxes/
